How to use a global pyrightconfig.json in neovim?
In my neovim setup, I enabled pyright lsp with lspconfig, I think by default it looks for a pyrightconfig.json at the root of your project path, but how to set it so that it looks first for a local pyrightconfig.json, then if not found it looks at a global pyrightconfig.json (eg $ROOT/pyrightconfig.json), or at least look only at a global pyrightconfig.json instead of a local one ? I saw this link that references all pyright settings in neovim, but there isn't any setting that interacts with the pyright config path.
